# Unable to show the button in Teams mobile app

Tags: json, microsoft-teams

The code below is workable in Microsoft Teams Desktop version. 
But the button unable to show in Teams mobile app.

Anyone can help ? ty pls refer below photo attachment

```
{"@type": "MessageCard",
                "title": "System Alert",
                "text" : "Network Error",
                "themeColor": "E81123",
                "potentialAction": [
            {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "ActionCardName",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "TextInput",
                    "id": "comment",
                    "title": "Enter your comment",
                    "isMultiline": "true"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
            "@type": "HttpPOST",
            "name": "OK",
            "target": "https://ptsv2.com/t/ANA/post",
            "body": "comment={{comment.value}}"
                }
            ]
         }

        ]
    }
```

[Mobile APP views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPaTA.png)

[Desktop views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMCud.png)

Answer (score 1):

We call that feature Actionable Messages and I'm afraid that's not supported on mobile versions of Teams yet. It's definitely on the roadmap but we don't have an ETA yet.

Comment: ok thanks for reply...hope that feature can support in mobile version ASAP.

Comment: It's long overdue.